# Importing .xls to Access .mdb: External Table is not in the expected format

Tags: excel, ms-access, import, vba

I have a macro that imports a spreadsheet as follows:  (this spreadsheet is an export from a web-based application, and during the initial export the chosen format is 97-2003)

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "d2s_safety_tbl", _
"\\company.com\dfsroot$\Share\office_public\D2S\D2S\D2S_Scorecard\Source Data\D2S\D2S Safety.xls", True
```

When importing to Access, I get:

`Run-time Error '3274': External table is not in the expected format.`

When I open this Excel file, I get a dialog

`"The file you are trying to open is in a different format than specified by the file extension..."`

So the file name is .xls, my computer tells me its the 97-2003 Format, but once I open the file and click save, it defaults to save it as a Web Page format with the option to save as .xls.  What gives?

UPDATE: If I open the file, then Save As .xls format (seemingly redundant, but apparently not), it asks me if I want to overwrite the existing file, so I do.  Once I go through this, the VBA import is successful.  I can't have the clerk go through this process every week--any way to avoidd this?  Possibly the initial export from the web-based application?

Comment: Have you tried opening the strange file in Notepad (or similar) to see if it really is just an HTML file with an `.xls` extension?

Comment: When I do, I get my 4 headings and the ~100 rows of data, but with sorts of HTML partitioning it

Comment: Does the file contain an HTML `<table>` tag?

Comment: It starts with `<html><body><table border=1><tr><td style='font-weight: bold;'>CASE NUMBER</td><td style='font-weight: bold;'>PERSON HISTORY-EMPLOYEE NUMBER</td><td style='font-weight: bold;'>INJURY DATE</td><td style='font-weight: bold;'>RECORDABLE</td></tr>` then provides all the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` is refusing to import your `.xls` file because it is not really an `.xls` file, it is an HTML file that has been given an `.xls` file extension. Providing a "fake" file extension is a trick that I've seen other "developers" use, and it really is a Bad Idea (for the reasons we've seen here).

If the keepers of the upstream system balk at doing The Right Thing and fixing their code to produce a *real* `.xls` file then try renaming the "`.xls`" file to `.htm` and importing it using

```
DoCmd.TransferText acImportHTML, ...
```

Comment: I'll give that a try.  Even as `.htm` it should still import the appropriate amount of columns with appropriate column names?

Comment: @TrevorD You can run through the import process manually and create an Import Specification (just like with CSV and other text files)

Answer (score 0):

I also got a 3274 error when importing a spreadsheet into Access.  I have been using this macro for a while now.

The solution was to compact and repair the Access database.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem along with another problem (office 2016 x64): Pasting from excel to access raised 'Data on the Clipboard is damaged,...' error. I found a workaround by clicking on the lower right button in paste section of home tab of access, opening the **clipboard pane**.
After opening Clipborad Pane as stated above, my DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet surprisingly worked fine.
I don't know why but it may help those having the same problem and those trying to find a real solution.