# Office from 2007 updated to 2013 breaks command

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-office

Before our office switched from 2007 to 2013 office, I was using a `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` method that was working perfectly. This was the code I was using.

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "TableName", strDropFile, -1
```

However, now that we switched, I'm getting the error that says `an external table is not in the expected format.` I'm not sure if, because of the change to Office 2013, there should be a different Spreadsheet type used in the method.

Does anyone know if the `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel` part changes now that I'm using Office 2013? I'm confused because the file extension is the same and I'm not exactly sure if this is the issue.

Comment: Could it have anything to do with this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21385438/importing-xls-to-access-mdb-external-table-is-not-in-the-expected-format

Comment: Or maybe this? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2836058

Comment: If you open the excel file manually and save it, does the import work then?  If not, have you tried manually importing the spreadsheet through the Access GUI?

Comment: I've tried importing the file manually through Access in both .xls and .xlsx and they both don't work. The only thing I can think of is that there is something incompatible with the 2007 Access application and the 2013 Excel file.

Comment: 1) When the manual import does not work, do you see an error message?
2) Are you positive it is an Excel file?  (If you open it in Notepad, does it look like garbage, or can you read words?)

Answer (score 0):

I've had this sort of issue with exporting to Excel. Try leaving out the  SpreadsheetType.

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "TableName", strDropFile, -1
```

Comment: So I found what was causing the problem, which is simple ignorance on my part from not working a lot with Access and VBA. I was running through the code where it would open the Excel Object that I created. Through the method of opening the workbook (Workbooks.Open) it would fail. Each time that it would fail, I would leave an Excel process open. I had to go into the Task Manager and end all excel processes that were opened through the method. After I closed everything down, it worked. If someone knows why, they should let everyone else know.